# GCP Virtual Machine doesnt show Data for Top processes by CPUMetrics Ops Agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, monitoring, google-cloud-ops-agent

I've installed the ops agent on one of our Virtual machines. The disk, memory, network traffic all show proper data in Monitoring tab.

However, the CPU tab only shows CPU utilization.

The top processes by CPU show "no data available for selected time Frame". At first, I thought it was still gathering information, but its been days and it still doesnt show anything at any time frame.

[Top Process by CPU image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKG53.png)

What do I need to configure for the data to become viewable ? I couldn't find anything online about this. Thank you

Comment: Anyine has anything helpful  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have default configurations for ops agent then both the monitoring and logging should be available. Also please do note that "processes metrics" are only retained for 24 hours. So, if you are choosing any time frame apart from this the data will not be available.

Hope this helps!